# Choose best input to OCR from two images

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I'm building a pre-processing project to enhance the OCR results that will happen in stage 2, but from two images.

For example I have image1, and image2, and we need to check which one is better to do the OCR on it.

The performance and process time is so important (real-time application).

Here are some cases I need to discuss about:

**Case1**:

[image]

Both are "F" letter, but the first one is readable "F" in the OCR that will happen next, where the second one is not readable at all, so for case 1 I need to choose the first "F" as an input for the OCR and ignore the second image.

**Case2**:

[image]

Both are "R" letter, and both are readable in the OCR, but the first one is better from the second one as we see, so I need to choose the first "R" here.

**Case3:**

[image]

It's similar to first case, where the "n" here is not readable in the OCR so I need to choose the first "na"

**Case4**:

[image]

In the first "na" the "n" and "a" are not merged together, where the second one they are one "contour" so the first "na" is much better to be the input to the OCR.

I need to build a generic fast algorithm to check if this part of the image is better for the OCR or not.

**I tried the following:**

1- Method1: Check if the image is blurry or not, and choose the one which is better.

2- Method2: called canny method (or sobel) and choose the image that's better.

3- Method2: check count of contours on both the image and choose the one that's seems better according to contours area, and counts.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The question is how do you get these chunks?

How do you decide that these are the things to compare.

If you know the sizes of expected characters - so you cut the chunks at that size - then you can use that as well in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a bit too broad. For different types of defects I would suggest different approaches.

For the first 2 cases and possibly the third, I would suggest doing a small morphological `close` and comparing the result with the original. The better letter would change less using close since it doesn't have small holes and dots. The comparison metric can be as simple as a sum over a pixelwise absolute difference.

Answer (score -1):

You can try morphological operations.Have a look on this.
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: How could Morphological Operations gives an estimate of better solution ?

Comment: For case 2 the black pixels in the letter R is missing so using appropriate kernal we can fill the missing pixels.In Case 4 the letters are connected using thinning operation or skeletonization we can separate it.then apply erosion to increase the width.If you are using tesseract for character recognition it gives poor performance with the smaller resolution images.Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but the question is about finding which one is better not enhancing the the bad input.

Comment: ok.if you can form good template for each cases.you can match the template with each character.then based on the similarity you can choose the better one.

Comment: Template matching in this case is similar to the ocr!